# mysql table columns not displayed in php when selected from html checbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am pursing data from mysql to php and showing it in browse. I have used checkbox (column) that will be selected by user. Only those columns will then be displayed.

The columns appear only if i select all the checkbox, if any one is not selected the table does not appear and gives error "Undefined index: checkboxName".

Please check my below code which is used for filtering the specific columns.

```
<?php if($_POST['Date'] == 'Date') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Date / Hour</th>
<?php if($_POST['Ingress'] == 'Ingress') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Ingress</th>
<?php if($_POST['Egress'] == 'Egress') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Egress</th> 
<?php if($_POST['Attempts'] == 'Attempts') { ?>  
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Attempts</th>  
<?php if($_POST['ASR'] == 'ASR') { ?>  
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">ASR</th>    
<?php if($_POST['ACD'] == 'ACD') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">ACD</th>
<?php if($_POST['CER'] == 'CER') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">CER</th>
<?php if($_POST['TQI'] == 'TQI') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">TQI</th>
<?php if($_POST['min'] == 'min') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Minutes</th>
```

Comment: I don't see usage of `checkboxName` in this code

Comment: All of these `if` blocks are nested within each other.  So, yes, later `if` blocks will only execute if earlier ones are also true.

Answer (score 0):

You're using curly brackets `{}` in your code, but you don't have a single escaping curly brace `}` to enclose your if's.

Either add those, or you this syntax instead:

```
<?php if($_POST['Date'] == 'Date'): ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Date / Hour</th>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_POST['Ingress'] == 'Ingress'): ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Ingress</th>
</php endif; ?>
```

Regarding your `Undefined index` error - Make sure that you validate that these `$_POST` variables are actually set (using the PHP [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function)

Comment: I have used closing brackets at the end of tables for each one i have opened. I am also sure other things are fine as i am getting the output table when i mark all the checkbox items. it does not work only when some are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a syntax error. Please use close bracket.

```
<?php if($_POST['Date'] == 'Date') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Date / Hour</th>
<?php } else if($_POST['Ingress'] == 'Ingress') { ?>
<th style="border: 1px solid #333333; height: 20px; background: #9999E6;font-weight: bold;">Ingress</th>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have closing bracket at the end for each opened ones.

Answer (score 0):

You made your code way more complicated than necessary:
use a css file and add the style to a class (or the th tag), link the css in the `<head>`-tag

```
.myClass {
 border: 1px solid #333333;
 height: 20px;
 background: #9999E6;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Your code would look like:

```
<?php if($_POST['Date'] == 'Date') ?>
<th class="myClass">Date / Hour</th>
<?php if($_POST['Ingress'] == 'Ingress') ?>
<th class="myClass">Ingress</th>
<?php if($_POST['Egress'] == 'Egress') ?>
<th class="myClass">Egress</th> 
<?php if($_POST['Attempts'] == 'Attempts') ?>  
<th class="myClass">Attempts</th>  
<?php if($_POST['ASR'] == 'ASR') ?>  
<th class="myClass">ASR</th>    
<?php if($_POST['ACD'] == 'ACD') ?>
<th class="myClass">ACD</th>
<?php if($_POST['CER'] == 'CER') ?>
<th class="myClass">CER</th>
<?php if($_POST['TQI'] == 'TQI') ?>
<th class="myClass">TQI</th>
<?php if($_POST['min'] == 'min') ?>
<th class="myClass">Minutes</th>
```

You could take it one step further:

```
<?php
  $arr = {
    'Date' => 'Date / Hour',
    'Ingress' => 'Ingress',
    'Egress' => 'Egress',
    'Attempts' => 'Attempts',  
    'ASR' => 'ASR',  
    'ACD' => 'ACD',
    'CER' => 'CER',
    'TQI' => 'TQI',
    'min' => 'min', 
   };

 foreach( $arr as $index => $value ) {
  if (isset($_POST[ $index] && $_POST[ $index ] == $index) )
    echo "<th class='myClass'>$value</th>";
 }
```

?>